# Wordpress footer cross-browser floating misbehaviour

Tags: css, html, wordpress, footer

The footer of my wordpress behaves differently in chrome and in firefox. In chrome the right part of my footer moves even though it should be aligned with the left part. In firefox it works fine.

A skeleton of the page can be found here:
http://sometestdomain.comeze.com/3-2/
Any ideas how to solve this problem??

Here's the relevant part of my CSS

```
div.front-widgets * h3 {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.template-front-page.two-sidebars .widget-area .front-widgets {
    background: #2c2c2c;
    float: left;
    width: 60.9375%;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 1.714285714rem;
    height: 17.857142rem;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
.template-front-page .widget-area .widget {
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
.template-front-page .widget-area .widget:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: right;
}
.template-front-page .widget-area .widget:nth-child(even),
.template-front-page.two-sidebars .widget-area .front-widgets + .front-widgets {
    float: right;
    width: 39.0625%;
}
```

Comment: That site looks identical in Firefox and Chrome -- are you sure you're looking at the latest versions?

Comment: Please post the problem HTML as well as your CSS.  Or better yet make a jsfiddle to boil the problem down.

Comment: On the first page there is no Problem, but when i iterate through the menu e.g. onto this page http://sometestdomain.comeze.com/3-2/ the right part of the footer moves in my chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome the parent div of the .front-widgets confuses the proper rendering of the second .front-widgets element. If you just assign some height to the #secondary object it will fix the problem.

something like:

```
#secondary {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

should do the trick for chrome =)